# Iterating through elements of variable arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, argument-unpacking

I have a function `scalar_func(*args)` that takes a variable number scalar numbers. It preforms some math with them and outputs a scalar. As a trivial example, we'll assume `scalar_func` multiplies each number:

```
def scalar_func(*args):
    out = 1    
    for arg in args:
        out *= arg
    return out
```

I would like to have `scalar_func` work with lists. To do so, I made another function `list_func(*args)`. It takes in a variable number of lists and makes a new one like so:

```
def list_func(*args):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(arg[0])):
         out.append(scalar_func(arg[0][i], arg[1][i], arg[2][i]...)
    return out
```

Obviously, this function is just pseudocode. How can I implement `list_func`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) here:

```
def scalar_func(*values):
    return sum(values)

def list_func(*args):
    out = []
    L = list(zip(*args))
    for i in range(len(args[0])):
         out.append(scalar_func(*L[i]))
    return out

list_func([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])  # [3, 5, 7]
```

If you have large lists, you may wish to create an iterator and use `next` to reduce memory consumption:

```
def list_func(*args):
    out = []
    L = iter(zip(*args))
    for i in range(len(args[0])):
         out.append(scalar_func(*next(L)))
    return out
```

This may also be rewritten for greater efficiency:

```
def list_func(*args):
    return [scalar_func(*i) for i in zip(*args)]
```

Alternatively, you can [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) for the functional equivalent:

```
from itertools import starmap

def list_func(*args):
    return list(starmap(scalar_func, zip(*args)))
```